# cannot find saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile method in scala api of Spark 1.2.0

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

My Environment: scala 2.11.7, spark 1.2.0 on CDH
spark-assembly-1.2.0-cdh5.3.8-hadoop2.5.0-cdh5.3.8.jar

I get data from mongo with spark. But saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile method could not be find. Only saveAsTextFile, saveAsObjectFile methods are available for save.

```
val mongoConfig = new Configuration()
mongoConfig.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.0.211:27017/chat.article")
mongoConfig.set("mongo.input.query","{customerId: 'some mongo id', usage: {'$gt': 30}")
val articleRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(mongoConfig, classOf[MongoInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[BSONObject])

val outputConfig = new Configuration()
outputConfig.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.0.211:27017/chat.recomm")
articleRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("", classOf[Object], classOf[BSONObject],
  classOf[MongoOutputFormat[Object, BSONObject]], outputConfig)
```

This is my screen capture in Intellij IDEA
[image]

Following is my build.sbt：

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop" % "mongo-hadoop-core" % "1.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.5.0-cdh5.3.8"
```

【spark-assembly-1.2.0-cdh5.3.8-hadoop2.5.0-cdh5.3.8.jar】 is not in sbt. I found in cdh home directory and moved it to my project dir manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the method is not in that package but rather in the following one :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

You might want to check compatibility of the mongo-hadoop-core package so you can use the proper one for Spark 1.2

Comment: This is just i use. It doesn't work. sc.newAPIHadoopRDD is available, but articleRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile not.

Comment: what is the type of your articleRDD ? It must be of type `RDD[(Object, BSONObject)])`

Comment: it is just this type as i define in above code(val articleRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(mongoConfig, classOf[MongoInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[BSONObject])).

Comment: This is not a type, the type of articles is `RDD[(Text, BSONObject)]`. Can you update your question with your pom.xml (formatted please)

Comment: It doesn't work even if I change it to RDD[(Object, BSONObject)])

Comment: I don't use spark-assembly, did you run sbt update ?

Comment: actually, I just put these jar files into my project file/lib. Additionally, I can't find the saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile in https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Comment: They also have to be present in your uber-jar

Comment: You mean spark classpath in Server? Yes, it has the whole copy of these jar.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, I have to try another solution.